# Services Inside GKE Cluster not Visible in Anthos Service Mesh Dashboard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, google-anthos-service-mesh

I have been trying to apply Managed Anthos Service Mesh on top of an autopilot GKE cluster and view the services in the topology section of the Anthos Service Mesh dashboard, but only one of roughly 10 services contained within said GKE cluster is visible. The following screenshot contains what I'm currently able to see on the dashboard:

[Service Mesh Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c30l.png)

Has anyone come across this issue and, if so, how was it solved? Please feel free to ask me to elaborate and share details that would be of use. Thank you!

I created an autopilot GKE cluster manually using the console and selected the option to enable the Anthos Service Mesh, after which I checked to ensure it was registered with ASM. I then deployed the services into said cluster and the dashboard was empty. Finally, I ensured the necessary Istio components were present but I could not see any of the services I had deployed in the topology.

Comment: Did you enable sidecar injection for the namespace where your workloads are running ? and restarted the workloads to put them in the mesh ?